# Is it possible to create a Paypal subscription that changes price over time?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm new here; I hope this question makes sense.

I'm interested in creating a subscription that reduces over time, to reward long-term users. For example, let's say the full price is $50/month. The subscription would charge that for the first 3 months. Then the next 3 months it would reduce to $40/month. The next 3 months it would drop again to $30/month... and so on until it ends up at $10/month indefinitely.

If the user cancels (or the card/account cannot be charged), if they return to resume their account, they start again at the $50/month price.

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, are there any suggestions for how I might approach it? Thanks!

(EDIT: Note that we need at least 5 price tiers, and possibly up to 8.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible to achieve your requirement with PayPal subscription button. You can use 3 different price with one subscription plan.

Follow below steps to create PayPal subscription button with your requirement:

- Login to PayPal
- Navigate to Profile > Profile and setting > My selling tools
- Click "*update*" besides *PayPal buttons* under *Selling Online* section
- In the next page, Click "*Create new button*" link under *Related Items* section and enter below details
- **Choose Button Type** : Subscriptions
- Enter **Item name** and choose your **currency**
- Scroll Down and enter **Billing amount each cycle** : 10
- Check "**I want to offer a trail period**"
- Enter **Amount to bill for the trail period** : 50
- Choose trail period(month) : 3
- Then check **Do you want to offer a second trail period**
- Enter 40 as Amount and choose 3 as month period
- Then Save your button, copy your code and use it.

Comment: Thank you. It's a great suggestion, but that limits me to 3 price tiers. I need at least 5 price tiers (and perhaps up to 8 price tiers).